# Scipy.signal peak width cannot fit the graph

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scipy

I created several functions to get the peak locations and peak width of some data. It works fine when I use `find_peak`, but I cannot use the `scipy.signal.peak_width` to fit my graph. Is there any solution to this? If `peak_width` cannot work, any other way to get the peak width?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_prominences, peak_widths

# x and y points of the peaks
def peaks_locs(x, y, peaks):
    x_peaks=[]
    y_peaks=[]

    for i in peaks:
        x_peaks.append(x[i])
        y_peaks.append(y[i])
    
    print(f"This is the location of peaks: {x_peaks}")
    print(f"This is the intensity of peaks: {y_peaks}")
    return x_peaks, y_peaks

def identify_peaks(x, y):
    peaks, properties = find_peaks(y, prominence=0.01, distance=1, height=0.5)
    prominences = peak_prominences(y, peaks)[0]
    peak_width = peak_widths(y, peaks, rel_height=0.5)

    return peaks, peak_width

def get_xy(filename):
    #### get x and y from original data file
    x=[]
    y=[]
    largest=0
    with open(filename) as expFile:
        i = 0
        flag = 0
        isMev=True
        for line in expFile:
            if i > 0 and line != '\n':
                data = line.split(',')
                if len(data) > 2 and flag == 2:
                    if float(data[0]) < -16:
                        isMev=False
                    if float(data[0]) > 8:
                        x.append(float(data[0]))
                        y.append(float(data[1]))
                        if x[-1] > 100 and y[-1] > largest:
                            largest = y[-1]
                elif len(data) == 1:
                    flag = flag + 1
            i += 1
    if isMev:
        x = [val * 8.06554 for val in x]

    return x, y

def xlim():
    choose_x1 = float(input("please type in first xlim"))
    choose_x2 = float(input("please type in second xlim"))
    return (choose_x1, choose_x2)

def title():
    title = input("Type in the name of the molecule")
    return title

# Identify peaks
file = get_xy('Pentacene_exp_laser_off_post_illum.dat') ### get x and y in INS spectra
peaks = identify_peaks(file[0],file[1]) 
peak_loc = peaks_locs(file[0], file[1], peaks[0]) ### get x and y locations of peaks
plot_peak(file[0],file[1], peak_loc[0], peak_loc[1], peaks[1])
```

Output:

[image: This is the graph I got.]

Updated:

For test_data, at the very end of the code, please use

```py
    x = np.linspace(0, 10 * np.pi, 1000)
    y = np.sin(x) + 0.6 * np.sin(2.6 * x)
    peaks = identify_peaks(x, y)
    peak_loc = peaks_locs(x, y, peaks[0]) 
    plot_peak(x, y, peak_loc[0], peak_loc[1], peaks[1])
```

Results with this data:
[image]

Here are the expected results:

[image: expected]

But as you can see, the orange line in my plot is not positioned correctly.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is/what isn't working? What is your expected result? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (we do not have the data you are testing with; maybe add some code to generate a representative dataset).

Comment: I just uploaded another picture, my expectation is like the red line in the picture, can draw a horizontal line at the full width at half maximum.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you Jared, I put the reproducible example here, sorry for the late response.

Comment: Where is the expected results plot from?

Comment: I used my code to run it and that's the result I got.

Comment: I was referring to the plot that looks like it has the colors inverted (black background with white axes).

Comment: Oh, I got it. My graph is the white one with blue peak, the black graph is my expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating this. Looking at the documentation of [`peak_width`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_widths.html), the return gives a tuple of 4 values: peak width, peak height where the widths were evaluated (in your case, halfway up), the left value of the width at that height, and the right value of the width at that height.

Now, it is important to note that the `peak_width` function does not consider the x values. So, when it returns the left and right values, those are in the range from 0 to number of elements in your dataset. So, you need to remap the before plotting them. This can be done manually or using an interpolator. I'll show you both.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

x = np.linspace(0, 10 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x) + 0.6 * np.sin(2.6 * x)

peaks, _ = find_peaks(y)
widths, half_heights, leftvals, rightvals = peak_widths(y, peaks, rel_height=0.5)


def remap(num, oldmin, oldmax, newmin, newmax):
    oldrange = oldmax - oldmin
    newrange = newmax - newmin
    return (num - oldmin)*newrange/oldrange + newmin


def remap_numpy(num, oldmin, oldmax, newmin, newmax):
    return np.interp(num, [oldmin, oldmax], [newmin, newmax])


leftvals = remap(leftvals, 0, len(x), x[0], x[-1])
rightvals = remap(rightvals, 0, len(x), x[0], x[-1])

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x[peaks], y[peaks], "x")
plt.hlines(half_heights, leftvals, rightvals, color="tab:red")
plt.show()
```

[image]